# Implementing the PCG random number generator

Tags: programming, random

PCG ("permuted congruential generator") is a recently-introduced random number generator.

> PCG is a family of simple fast space-efficient statistically good algorithms for random number generation. Unlike many general-purpose RNGs, they are also hard to predict.
>
> Source: *[PCG, A Family of Better Random Number Generators](http://www.pcg-random.org/)*

There's a [minimal 9-line implementation in C](http://www.pcg-random.org/download.html), along with C, C++, Haskell and also [Python](http://paddy3118.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/random-number-generator-pcg32.html) implementations.

**How can we implement the PCG directly in *Mathematica*?**

I've translated the 9-line C into *Mathematica*, but I'm now very confused thanks to *Mathematica*'s internal representation of integers (32-bit? 64-bit? N-bit?) so I'm not sure I've done it correctly, let alone optimally.

```
pcgRandomR[state_, inc_] := 
 Module[{oldstate, newstate, xorshifted, rot},
    oldstate = state;
    newstate = oldstate*6364136223846793005 + BitOr[inc, 1];
    xorshifted = BitShiftRight[BitXor[BitShiftRight[oldstate, 18], oldstate], 27];
    rot = BitShiftRight[oldstate, 59];
    {BitOr[BitShiftRight[xorshifted, rot], 
        BitShiftLeft[xorshifted, BitAnd[-rot, 31]]], newstate, inc}
  ]
```

This is my translation of the seeding function found [here on PCG.SE](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/42343/implement-a-pcg). Again, not really sure about correctness due to the representation of integers.

```
pcgRandomRSeed[initstate_, initseq_] := Module[{state, inc, rand},
     state = 0;
     inc = BitOr[BitShiftLeft[initseq, 1], 1];
     {rand, state, inc} = pcgRandomR[state, inc];
     state += initstate;
     {rand, state, inc} = pcgRandomR[state, inc];
     {state, inc}
  ]
```

Having sorted out those problems in defining the PCG, is it then possible to plug it into the random framework as our own custom RNG using `` Random`InitializeGenerator[gsym, opts] `` (as per ["Defining your own generator"](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html#215995533))?

Comment: So, the question is "...is it then possible to plug it into the random framework as our own custom RNG..."? Then the answer is yes.

Comment: 64-bit, signed, in recent 64-bit versions. 32-bit, signed, for 32-bit versions and all versions before 9.

Comment: This looks interesting. I've some experience with implementing new PRNG algorithms with the provided framework; I'll give this a whirl on the weekend.

Comment: @OleksandrR. thanks for clearing that up - do you have a reference?

Comment: @blochwave The reference is the LibraryLink documentation, which mentions this for *machine integers*.

Comment: @blochwave I implemented a LibraryLink version of this [but I'm starting to lose my confidence in the generation framework](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91523/why-doest-seedrandom-work-here), so I got stuck ...

Comment: @Szabolcs ah right, didn't think to look in LibraryLink. I also thought about linking to the C version, but wanted to see if it could be done directly in MMA. Then hit the problem with integers...

Comment: No reference that I can remember, sorry. But you can verify it using `Developer\`MachineIntegerQ`.

Comment: After going through the paper as best as I can, some of the stuff raised [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35081) seems relevant.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some amount of effort, I managed to come up with an implementation of O'Neill's "XSH-RR" family of permuted congruential generators. The following covers the 8-, 16-, 32-, and 64-bit generators, and the `mcg`, `oneseq`, and `setseq` variants. (I'll leave the modification to handle the `unique` variant as an exercise for the interested reader.) A similar approach can be done with the other PCG families.

First, here is a routine to rotate bits to the right:

```
BitRotateRight[n_Integer, r_Integer?NonNegative, bits : (_Integer?Positive) : 32] /;
               BitAnd[bits, bits - 1] == 0 := BitShiftRight[n, r] + 
               BitShiftLeft[BitAnd[n, BitShiftLeft[1, r] - 1], bits - r]
```

(This effectively generalizes Daniel's code [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/35090).)

Here is a set of default multipliers and increments for the underlying linear congruential generators. These and the following were adapted from O'Neill's code [here](https://github.com/imneme/pcg-c/blob/master/include/pcg_variants.h):

```
$PCGDefaultMultipliers = {141, 12829, 747796405, 6364136223846793005, 
                          47026247687942121848144207491837523525};

$PCGDefaultIncrements = {77, 47989, 2891336453, 1442695040888963407, 
                         117397592171526113268558934119004209487};
```

A few error messages:

```
PermutedCongruential::bw = "The value of the option \"BitWidth\"\[Rule]`1`
should be a power of two or Automatic.";
PermutedCongruential::nm = "No built-in multiplier available for
\"BitWidth\"\[Rule]`1`. Using \"BitWidth\"\[Rule]32 instead.";
PermutedCongruential::ni = "No built-in increment available for
\"BitWidth\"\[Rule]`1`. Using \"BitWidth\"\[Rule]32 instead.";
```

Some options:

```
Options[PermutedCongruential] =
  {"BitWidth" -> Automatic, "Increment" -> Automatic, "Multiplier" -> Automatic};
```

Initialize the generator:

```
PermutedCongruential /: Random`InitializeGenerator[PermutedCongruential,
                                                   opts___] := 
Module[{flops = Flatten[{opts, Options[PermutedCongruential]}],
        bw, idx, inc, mul},

       bw = "BitWidth" /. flops;
       If[bw === Automatic, bw = 32, 
          If[! (IntegerQ[bw] && Positive[bw] && BitAnd[bw, bw - 1] == 0), 
             Message[PermutedCongruential::bw, bw]; Throw[$Failed]]];

       idx = BitLength[bw] - 2;

       mul = "Multiplier" /. flops;
       If[mul === Automatic, 
          If[1 <= idx <= 5, mul = $PCGDefaultMultipliers[[idx]], 
             Message[PermutedCongruential::nm, bw]; bw = 32;
             mul = $PCGDefaultMultipliers[[4]]]];

       inc = "Increment" /. flops;
       If[inc === Automatic, 
          If[1 <= idx <= 5, inc = $PCGDefaultIncrements[[idx]], 
             Message[PermutedCongruential::ni, bw]; bw = 32;
             inc = $PCGDefaultIncrements[[4]]], 
          inc = BitOr[BitShiftLeft[inc], 1]];

       idx = Min[Max[1, idx], 5];
       PermutedCongruential[bw, mul, inc, {BitShiftRight[bw + idx + 1],
                            bw - idx - 1, 2 bw - idx - 1}, 0]]
```

We define PCG as a bit generator:

```
PermutedCongruential[___]["GeneratesBitsQ"] := True
PermutedCongruential[bw_, rest__]["BitWidth"] := bw
```

This handles seeding:

```
PermutedCongruential[bw_, mul_, inc_, const_, state_]["SeedGenerator"[seed_]] :=
    Module[{ss = seed + BitAnd[inc, BitShiftLeft[1, 2 bw] - 1]},
           PermutedCongruential[bw, mul, inc, const, 
                                BitAnd[mul ss + inc, BitShiftLeft[1, 2 bw] - 1]]]
```

Finally, here is the bit generator:

```
PermutedCongruential[bw_, mul_, inc_, const_, state_]["GenerateBits"[bits_]] :=
    Module[{bot, ns, res, rot, xsh},
           {xsh, bot, rot} = const;
           ns = BitAnd[mul state + inc, BitShiftLeft[1, 2 bw] - 1];
           res = BitShiftRight[BitXor[state, BitShiftRight[state, xsh]], bot];
           res = BitRotateRight[BitAnd[res, BitShiftLeft[1, bw] - 1],
                                BitShiftRight[state, rot], bw];
           {res, PermutedCongruential[bw, mul, inc, const, ns]}]
```

---

As a test of the generator, let's reproduce some sample values given [here](http://www.pcg-random.org/using-pcg-c.html):

```
BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> {PermutedCongruential, "Increment" -> 54}];
            IntegerString[RandomInteger[{0, BitShiftLeft[1, 32] - 1}, 6], 16]]
   {"a15c02b7", "7b47f409", "ba1d3330", "83d2f293", "bfa4784b", "cbed606e"}
```

Test uniformity at various bit widths:

```
Table[DistributionFitTest[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42,
      Method -> {PermutedCongruential, "BitWidth" -> BitShiftLeft[1, k]}];
      RandomReal[1, 1*^5]], UniformDistribution[]], {k, 3, 6}]
   {0.988711, 0.951478, 0.228108, 0.181171}

Table[Histogram[BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, 
      Method -> {PermutedCongruential, "BitWidth" -> BitShiftLeft[1, k]}];
      RandomReal[1, 1*^5]], Automatic, "PDF", 
      PlotLabel -> StringForm["``-bit PCG", BitShiftLeft[1, k]]],
      {k, 3, 6}] // Partition[#, 2] & // GraphicsGrid
```

[image: histograms for the PCG generator at various bit widths]

At this point, I'd like to take this opportunity to present another method to visualize the randomness of a sequence. This is [Pickover's "noise sphere" visualization](http://dx.doi.org/10.1147/rd.351.0227):

```
noiseSphere[vals_?VectorQ, opts___] :=
     Graphics3D[{RGBColor[##], 
                 Sphere[Sqrt[#3] Append[Through[{Cos, Sin}[2 π #1]] Sin[π #2], 
                        Cos[π #2]], 1/50]} & @@@ Partition[vals, 3, 1],
                opts, Boxed -> False, Lighting -> "Neutral"]

BlockRandom[SeedRandom[42, Method -> {PermutedCongruential, "Increment" -> 54}];
            noiseSphere[RandomReal[1, 1*^4]]]
```

[image: "noise sphere" for PCG generator]

The lack of structure and uniform filling of the sphere visually demonstrate the (apparent) lack of correlation in the sequence generated by PCG.

Comment: From the looks of it, the only thing preventing the extension of PCG to 128 bits and higher is the lack of good (M)LCGs that are 256 bits or higher. Unfortunately, L'Ecuyer's listings only go up to 128 bits.

Comment: This is really cool, and really thorough - thank you!

Answer (score 17):

I just followed through with the tutorial "[Defining Your Own Generator](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/RandomNumberGeneration.html#215995533)".

Start with provided, a little tweaked functions. The key trick is to ensure that the bit-expandable Mathematica integers are of the size of relative machine unsigned integers. I use `BitAnd` with mask to accomplish that:

```
pcgRandomR[state_, inc_] := 
 Module[{ newstate, xorshifted, rot, mask32=2^32-1,mask64=2^64-1},
    newstate = BitAnd[state*6364136223846793005 + BitOr[inc, 1], mask64];
    xorshifted = BitAnd[BitShiftRight[
        BitXor[BitShiftRight[state, 18], state], 27], mask32];
    rot = Mod[BitShiftRight[state, 59], 32];
    {BitAnd[BitOr[
        BitShiftRight[xorshifted, rot], 
        BitShiftLeft[xorshifted, BitAnd[32 - rot, 31]
     ]], mask32], newstate, inc}
  ]

pcgRandomRSeed[initstate_, initseq_] := Module[{state, inc, rand},
     state = 0;
     inc = Mod[BitOr[BitShiftLeft[initseq, 1], 1], 2^64];
     {rand, state, inc} = pcgRandomR[state, inc];
     state = Mod[state + initstate, 2^64];
     {rand, state, inc} = pcgRandomR[state, inc];
     {state, inc}
  ]
```

Plug into the framework:

```
Options[PermutedCongruential] = {"InitState" -> Automatic, 
  "InitSeq" -> 7050702485517258437}

PermutedCongruential /:
 Random`InitializeGenerator[PermutedCongruential, opts___] :=
 Module[{initState, initSeq},
  initState = 
   Replace[OptionValue[PermutedCongruential, {opts}, "InitState"], 
    Automatic :> RandomInteger[{1, 2^64}]];
  initSeq = 
   Replace[OptionValue[PermutedCongruential, {opts}, "InitSeq"], 
    Automatic :> RandomInteger[{1, 2^64}]];
  If[! IntegerQ[initState], Throw[$Failed]];
  If[! IntegerQ[initSeq], Throw[$Failed]];
  PermutedCongruential @@ pcgRandomRSeed[initState, initSeq]
  ]
```

The generated random integers are 32-bits, hence the bit-width of the generator must be 32, rather 64, as was the case in my previous unsuccessful attempt at it:

```
PermutedCongruential[state_, inc_]["GeneratesBitsQ"] := True;
PermutedCongruential[state_, inc_]["BitWidth"] = 32;
PermutedCongruential[state_, inc_]["SeedGenerator"[seed_]] :=
 PermutedCongruential[Mod[state seed, 2^64], inc]

PermutedCongruential[state_, inc_]["GenerateBits"[bits_]] := 
    {#1, PermutedCongruential[##2]} & @@ pcgRandomR[state, inc]
```

It can now be used:

```
In[78]:= BlockRandom[
 SeedRandom[12324235, 
  Method -> {PermutedCongruential, "InitSeq" -> 32736465}];
 {RandomInteger[{1, 26}, 3], RandomReal[1, 3]}]

Out[78]= {{21, 9, 15}, {0.175217, 0.750743, 0.914359}}
```

The results appear to be good:

```
In[79]:= DistributionFitTest[BlockRandom[
  SeedRandom[12324235, 
   Method -> {PermutedCongruential, "InitSeq" -> 32736465}]; 
  RandomReal[1, 10^5]], UniformDistribution[]]

Out[79]= 0.925037
```

[image]

Comment: I think it's related to the point I raised in a comment: how are you supposed to "correctly" (whatever that means) [rotate bits](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/35081) in *Mathematica*?

Comment: @J.M. The issue was incorrect "BitWidth". I used 64, and it gives 32, which explained the atom at 0 I was seeing. The other issue was that I needed to truncate bit-expandable Mathematica integers to the proper widths as in C-code. I do this by `BitAnd`-ing with a mask now.

Comment: Amazing - this looks good, thank you!