# Restarting random number generators where you left off

Tags: random

I have code that uses both `RandomReal` and `RandomInteger` a number of times to produces a sequence of $n$ data sets.  After closing the notebook and quitting the kernel, I would like to be able to start the code where I left off in the random sequence, and generate an additional $m$ data sets.

I can do this with the old `Random` function and `$RandomState`.  But, how do I do it with `RandomReal` and `RandomInteger`?

Comment: Probably with ``Random`GetRandomState`` and ``Random`SetRandomState``.  These are undocumented and might crash your kernel.  I did get a crash with them yesterday.  Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91523/why-doest-seedrandom-work-here

Comment: But is it really important for your application where you are exactly in the random sequence?  Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: start with SeedRandom, keep count of the random calls.  Restart with same seed and make the right number of random calls to get back to the same point,

Comment: @george, but if one was doing Monte Carlo with a few million or so calls to the PRNG before you lost patience, you'd hope there was a convenient way to pick up where you left off without going through that first few million again, no? For a congruential generator, this is not too hard to do, but of course nobody uses purely congruential generators in a nontrivial Monte Carlo application…

Comment: @J.M. I see that "jumping ahead" by precisely $n$ steps is discussed for many different generators.  What is the practical use of this?

Comment: @Szabolcs, apart from reproducible results (e.g. the Monte Carlo example I gave in my previous comment), I'm not aware of any other good use. FWIW, I've seen some of those papers too, but implementing their ideas in *Mathematica* was not so straightforward for me.

Comment: For each of your n steps initialize SeedRandom with s+i where i runs from 1...n.  For each of your m steps initialize SeedRandom with s+i where i runs from n+1 to m.  Where s is 'some seed'.

Comment: `RandomInteger[]&/@Range[10^7]//Timing//First -> .55`

Comment: @george2079 Why not use `RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 10^7]` which is an order of magnitude faster and leaves the randomizer at the same state as yours.